# Using Address with Indirect to access cell on another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to create a table of data coming from two other worksheets when their Column A data match.
There are two ways for this to fail: Something in list A not in List B and something in List B not in List A.

Using VLOOKUP, I can pull cells from the rows that match, and some correctly return #N/A. Since the source sheets are not visible, I wanted to generate a list that finds the Address of the exact match and then use that to pull values from that row so I can be confirm I am getting the data from the same row for all columns.

I setup Named Ranges to make the search array easier to maintain. Here is my VLOOKUP and I change the "4" to another higher number to get adjacent columns.

```
=VLOOKUP('Element Templates V8_02'!$A3,V8_01_Element_Templates,4,FALSE)
```

So as my Address function, I created this formula to return the address of the column 1 match. This named range is only column A of the same worksheet as the above named range.

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH('Element Templates V8_02'!$A3,V8_01TemplatePathAndName,0),1,1)
```

This returns $A$3 in Cell I3.

Then I tried to use INDIRECT with the address in the above cell (I3) but I get a #REF error. (I get a #N/A if the ADDRESS function returned an #N/A, too.)

```
=INDIRECT("'V8_01_Element_Templates'!"&I3,TRUE)
```

Can I get a formula to accept the Address value of Cell I3 and also use Offset to get column offsets from that cell as well?

Bingo! I used the Named Range instead of the Tab Name. A Quick Edit and it's working great. Thanks for the second set of eyes.

Comment: It gives you the `#REF` error because `V8_01_Element_Templates` is a named range, and you're using it as a sheet name in the `INDIRECT` function. Also, try pasting a sample of your data to make understanding your situation easier.